# How to remove twig from symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, twig

My project does not need any twig functionality or templating for that matter.

I removed twig from

- composer.json
- bundles.php
- I removed all the config twig files (yml files)
- I removed the html templates (index.html.twig)

When I now run composer it says

```
    Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!
!!  In CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 86:
!!
!!    The service "web_profiler.controller.profiler" has a dependency on a non-ex
!!    istent service "twig". Did you mean one of these: "maker.maker.make_twig_ex
!!    tension", "maker.auto_command.make_twig_extension"?
!!
!!
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
```

What else did I forgot to remove?

Comment: Do you really need to remove it?  Isn't it just a case of not using it.

Comment: Why should I install packages I don't use ? Just wondering.

Comment: The difficulties you are facing show what problems it can cause.  It's not that you don't use them but there may be other packages that expect them to be there.  There may be modules installed in PHP you never use, but do you remove them?

Comment: Please share more details. How **exactly** did you remove Twig?

Answer (score 6):

You are using the web profiler, and while you do, you [need Twig](https://github.com/symfony/web-profiler-bundle/blob/c97712849f4f3e4ea0a1be7ff38fcefadaa55c47/composer.json#L25).

In this case, the statement *"My project does not need any twig functionality or templating for that matter"* is incorrect. You do not need this functionality on production, but you are using it (if indirectly) on development.

Your options are:

- Remove the Web Profiler Bundle (and any other package that requires Twig, running `composer why twig/twig` might be a good idea).
- Install twig only on dev (`composer install twig/twig --dev`)